# Office365 - cannot email DynamicDistributionGroup

Tags: groups, microsoft-office-365

I created a dynamic distribution group in O365 using PowerShell and PSSession. I can see my group, and see users that are member of this group.

but when I email my group, I received an error. If I look at the flow, the mail address is something very long, starting with : IMCEAEX-_o= [etc.]

Is that normal ? I shouldn't have group_adress@domain.onmiscrosoft.com ?

I don't know how to troubleshoot this at all ...

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

How/what steps did you follow setup the group?  What's the error you are getting?  Which sender are you using?

Most of the time folks forget to allow external senders to send to the group (if required):

```
Set-DistributionGroup "<Distribution Group Name>" -RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled $False
```

Or they fail to assign a proper email alias to the group:

```
Set-DistributionGroup "<Distribution Group Name>" -EmailAddresses SMTP:<Primary Email>,<Alias Email>
```

You can run a `Get-DistributionGroup` and verify all of your settings are accurate for the group.

Comment: As its o365, do I need to disable `RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled`  to allow `mydomain.com` to email `domain.onmicrosoft.com` ? but mydomain.com is accepted domain ...  
Email alias is long, but only alpha characters ... So I don't understand.

Comment: Only if mydomain.com is outside of the O365 organization that domain.onmicrosoft.com is a part of.  But again, the error you receive would tell you as such.  What's the error?

Comment: Answer my own post. Sorry to be new to this, and nervous, so I couldn't wait 1hour ... Thanks for your help though !

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have to admit that I was a really nervous for this.

But it works well ! In fact, It was the time that O365 and the ActiveDirectory (in the cloud) talk with each other. Everything's fine now.

So please, if you create group, grab a coffee, and wait for 1hour before testing anything out.

Comment: :) I was going to start off with that...but without the error message and the fact that you knew how to establish a PS session to O365 I figured you'd already waited for replication to occur.